# SQL find nearest matching values with 2 input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needs some help and i hope anyone here can help me.

I have a table that looks something like this:

| Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | 50 |
| 100 | 120 | 60 |
| 100 | 140 | 70 |
| 120 | 100 | 60 |
| 120 | 120 | 70 |
| 120 | 140 | 80 |

And so on..

Val1 and Val2 is input parameters and the users can choose any numeric value.
And I want to find Val3 depending on the users input.
If the input-value doesnt match anything in the table i want it to find the closest higher Value.

Exampel:
Val1 = 105 and Val2 = 130 i want to find 80 (Last row in the table).

Exampel 2:
Val1 = 105 and Val2 = 95 i want to find 60 (4th row in the table).

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can just find all the results and limit it to 1 which fulfills your criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Val1 >= param1 AND Val2 >= param2 
ORDER BY Val1, Val2 
LIMIT 1
```

Here, order by is important as you need the next greater value only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this helped me!

I did like yours but with a CTE and selected only top 1.

Comment: Why do you need an CTE here ? When you can achieve the same using a single query. Considering performance you should avoid the CTE version.